# Mongo Shell and .js script to rename collection by filtering part of name and comparing it to a var

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongo-shell

I am trying to build a .js script to be executed in a mongo shell that requires to do the following:

- obtain a list of all collection names with the word "CollectionUpgrade"
- separate the ending part of each collection name ( they are named as CollectionUpgrade_20 and 21 and 22 and so on up to 29) so I can compare it to the version schema (let's say 28) and if there are any CollectionUpgrade_30 or 31 to rename them as CollectionUpgrade_30_old and _31_old.
- list the renamed collections.

I have tried to find a way to do this for a while now but I can't seem to be getting anywhere and could use the wisdom of a mongoshell/js guru!

- I could not find a way to input into a query, I saw some posts about prompt password possibility to be used for the user to paste the exact collection name to be added in here:

  db.UpgradeCollection_XX.renameCollection("UpgradeCollection_XX_old");
- the names of the collection can differ like UsersCollectionUpgrade_22
- I'm only interested to match the end number to the schema and make sure no higher ones exist

I also tried a few if statements combined with a while but I didn't manage to get anywhere.

Another attempt was to ask the user to input the collection exact name into cmd input and turn that into a var I copy inside the above command then > fix.js and run this with mongo shell but that didn't come out exactly how I expected it - work in progress.

Sample of collection names in the DB:

```
Schema version:28
[
        "appInfosCollectionUpgrade_18",
        "appInfosCollectionUpgrade_20",
        "appInfosCollectionUpgrade_21",
        "appInfosCollectionUpgrade_27",
        "appInfosCollectionUpgrade_28",
        "collectionsCollectionUpgrade_22",
        "collectionsCollectionUpgrade_23",
        "collectionsCollectionUpgrade_27",
        "collectionsCollectionUpgrade_30",
        "configurationsCollectionUpgrade_10",
        "configurationsCollectionUpgrade_11",
        "configurationsCollectionUpgrade_12",
        "configurationsCollectionUpgrade_17",
        "configurationsCollectionUpgrade_20",
        "configurationsCollectionUpgrade_21",
        "configurationsCollectionUpgrade_26",
        "configurationsCollectionUpgrade_27",
        "configurationsCollectionUpgrade_6",
        "configurationsCollectionUpgrade_7",
        "configurationsCollectionUpgrade_8",
        "configurationsCollectionUpgrade_9",
        "districtsCollectionUpgrade_27",
        "subscriptionsCollectionUpgrade_19",
        "subscriptionsCollectionUpgrade_20",
        "subscriptionsCollectionUpgrade_21",
        "subscriptionsCollectionUpgrade_25",
        "subscriptionsCollectionUpgrade_27",
        "userCollectionUpgrade_30",
        "usersCollectionUpgrade_19",
        "usersCollectionUpgrade_20",
        "usersCollectionUpgrade_24",
        "usersCollectionUpgrade_25",
        "usersCollectionUpgrade_27",
        "usersCollectionUpgrade_31"
]
```

Any tips ideas or help on this would be a big help to this struggling human!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write an admin script based on your outline as follows:

```js
var newVersion = passwordPrompt();
var collectionsWithWordOnly = name => name.startsWith('CollectionUpgrade');
var olderVersionsOnly = name => {
  var [_, version, old] = name.split('_');
  if (old) {
    return false;
  }
  if (+version <= +newVersion) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
};
var renameAsOldVersion = (name) => {
  var newName = `${name}_old`;
  db[name].renameCollection(newName);
};
db.getCollectionNames()
  .filter(collectionsWithWordOnly)
  .filter(olderVersionsOnly)
  .forEach(renameAsOldVersion);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! i tried to add this part to a .js file that i launch from cmd  and it gives me a "." not expected, is there any way to encapsulate this for the .js script to read it as intended?

db.getCollectionNames()
 .filter(collectionsWithWordOnly)
 .filter(olderVersionsOnly)
 .forEach(renameAsOldVersion);

[js] SyntaxError: expected expression, got '.' @(shell):1:1

Comment: What version of MongoDb are you running? This script runs without any errors on `4.4.6`.

Comment: Its 4.0 limitation on the app side...i worked with cmd to replace promptPassword because that one is 4.2...